# How to store a Font in @AppStorage?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I want to let users choose a custom font.

```
import SwiftUI

class FontPickerVM: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("custom_font") var font: Font? = nil
    // @Published var font: Font? = nil
}

extension Font: RawRepresentable {
    public typealias RawValue = String
    
    
    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        
    }
    
    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        
    }
}
```

How do I implement `RawRepresentable` for `Font`?

---

I am using a `UIFontPickerViewController` to select a font.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

public struct SUIFontPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    private let onFontPick: (UIFontDescriptor) -> Void
    
    public init(onFontPick: @escaping (UIFontDescriptor) -> Void) {
        self.onFontPick = onFontPick
    }
    
    public func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SUIFontPicker>) -> UIFontPickerViewController {
        let configuration = UIFontPickerViewController.Configuration()
        configuration.includeFaces = true
        configuration.displayUsingSystemFont = false
        
        let vc = UIFontPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    public func makeCoordinator() -> SUIFontPicker.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self, onFontPick: self.onFontPick)
    }
    
    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UIFontPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: SUIFontPicker
        private let onFontPick: (UIFontDescriptor) -> Void
        
        
        init(_ parent: SUIFontPicker, onFontPick: @escaping (UIFontDescriptor) -> Void) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.onFontPick = onFontPick
        }
        
        public func fontPickerViewControllerDidPickFont(_ viewController: UIFontPickerViewController) {
            guard let descriptor = viewController.selectedFontDescriptor else { return }
            onFontPick(descriptor)
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        
        public func fontPickerViewControllerDidCancel(_ viewController: UIFontPickerViewController) {
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIFontPickerViewController,
                                       context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SUIFontPicker>) {
        
    }
}

struct FontPicker: View {
    
    @State var isFontPickerPresented = false
    @Environment(\.font) var defaultFont
    
    @StateObject var vm = FontPickerVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isFontPickerPresented = true
            printDetails()
        } label: {
            Text("Select font")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isFontPickerPresented) {
            SUIFontPicker { fontDescriptor in
                let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 18)
                vm.font = Font(newFont as CTFont)
                printDetails()
            }
        }
        .font(vm.font)
    }
    
    func printDetails(){
        print("default font:", defaultFont ?? "")
        print("custom font:", vm.font ?? "")
    }
}



struct FontPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Form {
            FontPicker()
            FontPicker()
        }
    }
}
```

I had to specify a size `UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 18)`, but I only want to change the font family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I only want to change the font family.

If that is the case, then you should set `configuration.includeFaces` to `false`, so that users can only select a family, but not the faces (Bold, Italic etc) in that family.

After that, the `UIFontDescriptor` returned by the `UIFontPickerViewController` should always have a `NSFontFamilyAttribute` key in its `fontAttributes`. Get the value of that key and store it in `AppStorage`.

Example:

```
@AppStorage("customFont") var fontFamily: String?

var customFont: Font {
    if let fontFamily {
        return Font.custom(fontFamily, size: 18)
    } else {
        return .body
    }
}

@State var showSheet = false

var body: some View {
    Text("Foo Bar Baz")
        .font(customFont)
        .onTapGesture {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SUIFontPicker { desc in
                fontFamily = desc.fontAttributes[.family] as? String
            }
        }
}
```

If there are other information in the font descriptor that you also want to save (though from my experience font descriptors from a `UIFontPickerViewController` doesn't have much "other information"), you can technically convert the font descriptor to `Data`, using `NSKeyedArchiver`. You can then store the `Data` in `@AppStorage`.

```
let fontData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: someFontDescriptor, requiringSecureCoding: true)
// store fontData into AppStorage
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, I didn't want to override the default font size. If I add `.font(.custom("San Francisco", size: 18))` at the root of the app, the headers in a `Form` are bigger than usual. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJu4V.png)

Comment: @BPDev You can get the default font size for a given `TextStyle` using `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: style).pointSize`, though I don't know what text style the section headers use. In any case, you can post a new question about this.